# keeping first unique row found when multiple columns are the same

Tags: matlab, unique, octave

I have an array sorted by the first column but **I only want to keep the first unique row found when both the second and third column are the same.**

I know I can get the first occurrence using `unique(array1(:,2), "first")` and `unique(array1(:,3), "first")`.  But **I want to keep the first unique row
when both the second and third column are the same**.

Example **array1:**

```
1   140.58939   226.65578
2   143.23078   227.31933
3   143.23078   227.31933
4   143.23078   227.83631
5   143.23078   229.79236
6   146.822     231.705
7   146.822     231.705
8   89.083      123.43
9   146.822     231.705
10  167.23      231.705
```

What I'm trying to get the array to look like **new_array1:**

```
1   140.58939   226.65578
2   143.23078   227.31933
4   143.23078   227.83631
5   143.23078   229.79236
6   146.822     231.705
8   89.083      123.43
10  167.23      231.705
```

Ps: I'm using Octave 4.0 which is similar to Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do this in Octave 4.0, using [`unique`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Sets.html#index-unique) and [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Rearranging-Matrices.html#index-sort):

```
[~, index] = unique(array1(:, 2:3), "rows", "first");
new_array1 = array1(sort(index), :);

new_array1 =

     1.0000   140.5894   226.6558
     2.0000   143.2308   227.3193
     4.0000   143.2308   227.8363
     5.0000   143.2308   229.7924
     6.0000   146.8220   231.7050
     8.0000    89.0830   123.4300
    10.0000   167.2300   231.7050
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[C,IA,~]=unique(array1(:,2:3),'rows');
array1_unique = array1(sort(IA),:)
```

Result:

```
array1_unique  =

1.0000  140.5894  226.6558
2.0000  143.2308  227.3193
4.0000  143.2308  227.8363
5.0000  143.2308  229.7924
6.0000  146.8220  231.7050
8.0000   89.0830  123.4300
10.0000  167.2300  231.7050
```

The direct return from unique, `C`, is a sorted array. Therefore, you also want to have the index vectors.

> [C,IA,IC] = UNIQUE(A,'rows') also returns index vectors IA and IC such that C = A(IA,:) and A = C(IC,:).

Note this is done in Matlab.